# Using Full text search Index in Sql Server 2008 with dynamic privacy setting on some columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have table with some indexed columns using full text search :

table Persons
    ID
    Name full indexed 
    Family full indexed 
    address full indexed

table privacyOnPerson
    PersonID
    AddressPrivacy AS boolean

when doing the following search term  = " NewYork "

Select ID , Name , Family , Address FROM Persons
WHERE FREETEXT(Address,"NEWYork")

but in this case I didn't take the privacy settings on address column in my consideration

how can I do that ???

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has no Boolean data type, did you mean bit? And without table structure and sample data it's hard to know what you want. But as a complete guess, you want to join the two tables together, something like this:

```
select 
    p.ID , 
    p.Name , 
    p.Family , 
    p.Address 
from
    dbo.Persons p
    join dbo.PrivacyOnPerson pp
    on p.ID = pp.PersonID 
where
    p.FREETEXT(Address,"NEWYork") and
    pp.AddressPrivacy = 0x0
```

Comment: yes I meant Bit datatype . thanks for your answer but what if I have many columns that have privacy . how can I write the join question to ignore only the columns that have privacy . note that the same record might have privacy on some columns and not in others .

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer without table structures and sample data, because you're asking about something that you developed, not something that is built into MSSQL. I think you have developed some logic to prevent users seeing the data in certain columns, based on dynamic conditions stored in another table?

Comment: ok my friend I will provide you with sample data :
first table : 
Members Table have the followings
ID  (PK)- FirstName - LastName - Salary
PrivacyMembers Table have the followings 
ID - MemberID (FK) - FirstNamePrivacy (bit) - LastNamePrivacy (bit)
SalaryPrivacy (bit)

 I have to use full text search on the first name , last name , salary columns but with taking the privacy table in my considerations